# User-defined type not defined when using Dictionary in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this piece of code a few weeks ago (well, I Frankensteined it off the internet) It was working perfectly. Now a few weeks later, im getting an error.

> Compile error: User-defined type not defined

Code below:

Function RangeToDict2 is causing the issue apparently

```
Sub Test()

    Dim d As Object
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim x As Variant

    HSBC_Column_mapping_Start = wks_macro.Cells.Find(What:="HSBC Column Names", MatchCase:=True, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(1, 0).Address
    HSBC_Column_mapping_End = wks_macro.Range(HSBC_Column_mapping_Start).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1).Address

    Set d = RangeToDict2(wks_macro.Range(HSBC_Column_mapping_Start & ":" & HSBC_Column_mapping_End))

    i = 1
    For Each Key In d.Keys
        Debug.Print "Key: " & Key & " Value: " & d(Key)

        'wkb_macro.Sheets(4).Range("A" & i).Value = Key
        i = i + 1
    Next



End Sub
Function RangeToDict2(ByVal R As Range) As Dictionary

    Set RangeToDict2 = New Dictionary
    i = 1
    Do Until i >= (R.Rows.Count * R.Columns.Count)
        RangeToDict2.Add R(i), R(i + 1)
        'Debug.Print R(i) & ", " & R(i + 1)
        i = i + 2
    Loop

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionary is part of the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library. It has to be added, in order to have access to it. 
Thus, in the VBA Editor, press Tools>References and click a checkmark to it:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a Microsoft Active X Data Object reference marked?

If not go to Tools > References and then look for Microsoft Active X Data Object Library.